# Reduce redirects for website - web.config

Tags: redirect

I need help with the (number of) redirects on my website.  At the moment I have 3 working redirects,

One goes from the WWW to the non www version.
Another goes from the non SSL to https.
Finally I removed Server header to increase security.

They work but I think they are slowing my site down.  Is there any way I can reduce the redirects to 2 ? I am looking for https://website.com

Here is my web.config:

```
    <configuration>
   <system.webServer>   
      <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
      </staticContent>
      <rewrite>        
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                      <conditions>
                         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                      </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" negate="false"></match>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http://website.com/{R:1}"></action>
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website\.com$" negate="true"></add>
                  </conditions>
                </rule>

            </rules>
        </rewrite>
         <rewrite>    
        <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
          <rule name="Remove Server header">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
          </rule>
        </outboundRules>

</rewrite>        
   </system.webServer>   
</configuration>
```

I came up with something like this but it seems to have made it worse   :

```
<rules>
<clear />
    <rule name="Redirect www and non-https to https://">
                  <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">                        
                         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website\.com$" negate="true"></add>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
     </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, I hope it can help someone with their SEO.
I got redirects down from the highs of:

- 3 redirects for using www ,
- 1 redirect for no www,
- 2 redirects for www (https)
- 0 redirects for no www (https)

to a maximum of 1:

- 1 redirect for www,
- 1 redirect for no www,
- 1 redirect for www(https)
- 0 redirects for no www(https)

I just needed to add a **s** in one line and remove **{HTTP_HOST}** and instead put in the website name.

```
<rewrite>    
       <rules>   
            <clear />             
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                      <conditions>
                          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                      </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>

                <rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />                  
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^website\.com$" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://website.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>

        </rules>
</rewrite>
```